# Multiple json serialization format

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

What I understand as one of the beauty from Json combinators in Play is that you can use the same model, but produce different json format by using different Writes combinators. Today I found a use case for this, but can't seem to be able to get it to work.

```
case class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String, city: String)

object Person {
  implicit val writes = (
    (__ \ "firstName").write[String] ~
    (__ \ "lastName").write[String] ~
    (__ \ "city").write[String])(unlift(Person.unapply))

  val cityWrites = (
    (__ \ "city").write[String])(unlift(Person.unapply))
}
```

The definition above gives me compile error as nameWrites does not match the case class definition. I can probably create a constructor override (this(lastName: String)), but it does not make sense for the model class. The purpose of this second Json is just to see which cities that we have customers in.

Can I influence the unlift operation here? I can't seem to be able to find documentation on it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm as in-the-dark as you are about `unlift()`, but from its type signature:

```
def unlift[A, B](f : (A) => Option[B]) : (A) => B
```

it seems to want a function that returns an `Option` around the fields you're trying to write.
So:

```
val cityWrites = (
  (__ \ "city").write[String])
  (unlift( (p:Person) => Some(p.city)) )
```

should do the trick for the `cityWrites` case.

And actually, just messing around with this stuff, I can do a `nameWrites` (which, I'm guessing you wanted to write the first and last names as JSON) without using `unapply` at all:

```
val nameWrites = (
  (__ \ "firstName").write[String] ~
  (__ \ "lastName").write[String])( (p:Person) => (p.firstName, p.lastName) )
```

And that looks pretty clear as well I think.

Edit: Here's how to use it as an `implicit` to write a list of `Person` objects:

```
object Person {
  val nameWrites = (
    (__ \ "firstName").write[String] and
    (__ \ "lastName").write[String])( (p:Person) => (p.firstName, p.lastName) )
}

...

val p1 = Person("John", "Smith", "Dallas")
val p2 = Person("Bob", "Smith", "Dallas")
val p3 = Person("Tom", "Smith", "Dallas")

val personList = List(p1, p2, p3)

implicit val nWrites: Writes[Person] = Person.nameWrites

println(Json.toJson(personList))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This works for the Json Writes. However now that the  return type has changed from Writes[Person] to Writes[String, String] as in your nameWrites example, how should I use it from Json.toJson. I use `Json.toJson(personList)(nameWrites)` and it gives me compile error on compatibility between Writes[Person] and Writes[String, String]. When I use `Json.toJson(personList.map((p:Person) => (p.firstName, p.lastName)))(nameWrites)`, it gives me compatibility error between Writes[String, String] and Writes[List[String, String]]. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with that then:

```
val cityWrites: Writes[Person] = new Writes[Person] {
  def writes(o: Person) = JsString(o.city)
}
```

And then to use it:

```
val serialized = Json.toJson(List[Person]())(Writes.list(cityWrites))
```

Still, I believe that in this case the best would be, as it contains no duplicates:

```
Json.toJson(List[Person]().map(_.city).distinct)
```

but I'm guessing you want to play it out with formats, right?

Comment: Thanks very much. Yes, this would work as well. My real case is actually trying to return more than one, but yes, yours is easier for single element.